# How to give Title in UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

[image: I want to title in image crop view][image: i want to give title in <code>UIImagePickerController</code> like following image screen shot.]

I want to give title in `UIImagePickerController` as shown in image screen shot

Comment: The title is **blank**, so you've already done it.

Comment: but how can i give title on that blank title?

Comment: i want to title in top view in second screen shot

Answer (score 1):

Set `UIImagePickerController` delegate to self and implement the following method of `UINavigationControllerDelegate`:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [viewController.navigationItem setTitle:@"<Your-Title>"];
}
```

Comment: Thnks ...but this method title in when i choose photo from picker not in this view

Comment: Ohh.. I don;t think we can set title over there as you can see there is no `NavigationBar` on editing screen. If you find any ways to this please do post it.

Answer (score 1):

You try this code:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
UINavigationItem *ipcNavBarTopItem;

// add done button to right side of nav bar
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Photos"
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                                              target:self 
                                                              action:@selector(saveImages:)];

UINavigationBar *bar = navigationController.navigationBar;
[bar setHidden:NO];
ipcNavBarTopItem = bar.topItem;
ipcNavBarTopItem.title = @"Photos";
ipcNavBarTopItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton;
}
```

Comment: i want to title in when i choose photo like in second screen shot .

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the delegate method for `UINavigationController`, in Swift:

```
func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    viewController.navigationItem.title = "Some title"
}
```