# how to give title in cropimageview ios sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to give title in `UIImagePickerController` like following image screen shot yellow color title shown below

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30295348/how-to-give-title-in-uiimagepickercontroller  See the link

Comment: @AshokLondhe  its over image not the navigation bar so link you gave doesnt answer for this questions